# How to make shortcut for :tabnew, :tabn, :tabp?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

In vim, I'd like to shorten `:tabnew` to `:tn`, `:tabp` to `:th`, `:tabn` to `:tl` somewhere in my `.vimrc`. Any idea how I would remap commands like this?

Comment: Note that `:tabn` can already be achieved by `gt` in normal mode, and likewise `:tabp` by `gT`. `1gt` will go to the first tab, `2gt` will go to the second, and so on.

Comment: I was after a `:te` -> `:tabedit` shortcut. This comment is to help people searching for that to find this question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [cabbrev](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:cabbrev):

```
ca tn tabnew
ca th tabp
ca tl tabn
```

Comment: ah that is really cool, when you go `:tn` then hit space, it auto-completes :tabnew

Comment: This is awesome. I was unaware of `cabbrev`.

Comment: Note that cabbrev expands abbreviations everywhere on the command line, i.e. when you enter `:%e th.txt`, the `th` will be expanded to `tabp`.

Answer (score 7):

you can add the following code in to the ~/.vimrc file and navigate through the tabs every easily.

```
nnoremap th  :tabfirst<CR>
nnoremap tj  :tabnext<CR>
nnoremap tk  :tabprev<CR>
nnoremap tl  :tablast<CR>
nnoremap tt  :tabedit<Space>
nnoremap tn  :tabnext<Space>
nnoremap tm  :tabm<Space>
nnoremap td  :tabclose<CR>
```

Comment: Just note that this overrides many uses of "t" (which finds a characters and places your cursor just before it - a variation of "f"). I mention this because I used to use these mapping until I realized I wanted "t" back.

Answer (score 6):

Daniel Kullmann points out the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6638381/102401) is dangerous.

If you use `ca tn tabnew`, anytime you type the string `th`, it can expand unexpectedly.

For example, `:!ls /tmp/tn/` will expand into `:!ls /tmp/tabnew/`

The approach listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7515418/102401) does not suffer the same problem. Using it would look like this:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> tn getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'tn' ? 'tabnew' : 'tn'
cnoreabbrev <expr> th getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'th' ? 'tabp' : 'th'
cnoreabbrev <expr> tl getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'tl' ? 'tabn' : 'tl'
cnoreabbrev <expr> te getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'te' ? 'tabedit' : 'te'
```

Those customizations ensure the expansion is done only on the commands and nowhere else.

Comment: The last `:te` shortcut for `:tabedit` wasn't part of the original question. I added it since searching for that answer was how I got to this page. Hopefully it'll help others get here faster.

Answer (score 4):

There is better way to navigate among tabs.
Just try (C is for Control):

```
nmap <silent> <C-n> :tabnext<CR>
nmap <silent> <C-p> :tabprev<CR>
imap <silent> <C-n> <esc><C-n>
imap <silent> <C-p> <esc><C-p>
```

Comment: You can do this with "gt" (tabnext) and "gT" (tabprev).

Answer (score 4):

```
"To create a new tab
nnoremap <C-t> :tabnew<Space>
inoremap <C-t> <Esc>:tabnew<Space>

"Tab Navigation
nnoremap <S-h> gT
nnoremap <S-l> gt
```

Comment: I just updated it like this: `nnoremap <C-t> :tabnew<CR>` and `inoremap <C-t> <Esc>:tabnew<CR>`. To open tab without pressing Enter.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the same mapping that is suggested here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17269521/2743772, and don't want to use other suggestions, try adding leader to the beginning and this way it doesn't overwrite **"t"**, unless of course you already have these exact mappings for something else.

```
nnoremap <Leader>th  :tabfirst<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>tj  :tabnext<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>tk  :tabprev<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>tl  :tablast<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>tt  :tabedit<Space>
nnoremap <Leader>tn  :tabnext<Space>
nnoremap <Leader>tm  :tabm<Space>
nnoremap <Leader>td  :tabclose<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl + PageUp` and `Ctrl + PageDown` move between tabs by default.

The shortcuts must not be bind by the terminal for this to work.
(I am on Ubuntu 18.04).