# vim change :x function to delete buffer instead of save & quit

Tags: vim, remap

I want to set `:x` in vim gui-mode to `delete buffer` because I always kill the whole gvim, which is kind of annoying. I know i can specifically set gui problems with `if has("gui running")` but don't know how to remap `:x`

thanks in advance

ps.: maybe the tag/term `remap` is wrong but I don't know the correct term, that's why google didn't provide any help at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim: Redefine a command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605036/vim-redefine-a-command)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I find the safest alternative is to use an expression abbreviation:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> x getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'x' ? 'bd' : 'x'
```

This will ensure the abbreviation will only be expanded to `bd` when `:x` is used otherwise just expand to `x`.

For more help:

```
:h map-<expr>
:h getcmdtype()
:h getcmdline()
```

Upon further inspection there appears to be a plugin that does exactly this by Hari Krishna Dara called [cmdalias.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746). It uses a variation of the technique above.

Answer (score 4):

This is not as easy as it looks. `:map` won't work with commands and `:command` only accepts commands that start with an uppercase letter. But you can use `:cabbrev`:

```
if has("gui_running")
  cabbrev x bd
endif
```

UPDATE: `:cmap` *could* actually be used: `:cmap x bd`, but it doesn't work right: each occurrence of `x` in a command is immediately replaced by `bd`.

EDIT: This question is a duplicate of [Can I (re)map Ex commands in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117150/can-i-re-map-commands-in-vim).

Comment: Why `has("gui running")`? I don't believe that'll ever be true. Should be `has("gui")`.

Comment: This has the problem then that if you ever enter "x" as a word, e.g. `:echo "1 + x = 3"` (convoluted, I know!), it'll be turned into `:echo "1 + bd = 3"`. @Peter's solution is better because it doesn't have this flaw.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan It should be `has("gui_running")`. It can be found in a list below `:h has-patch` (use `:helpg gui_running`).

Comment: @ZyX Correct, my mistake. I've used it before but didn't refer to it... `has('gui')` certainly won't cut it.