# Trying to write a Vim function / command?

Tags: vim

I'm using Janus (isn't pivotal to understand the question though). Basically what they do, is rewrite :e to be :Edit to work with NERDTree, but NERDTree doesn't support force opening a file (e.g. e!). So I had written something that rewrites :Edit! to :e!, but I like the benefits of using just :Edit!, so I'm trying to spoof if as if it was already built in. This is what I came up with:

```
ca Edit! e! <bar> Edit
```

The only problem, is that you can't do that for files that haven't been saved at least once. But I know doing

```
ca Edit! bd! <bar> Edit
```

will work: it will close the unsaved buffer and keep moving like nothing happened. All I need to do is write logic that will use the correct command in the right scenario all the time. Preferably the logic doesn't run on every page: only when I actually run the command should it attempt to figure it out. Any ideas?

Edit: I tried asking the #vim channel (gave me tons of help)... they said using expand("%")  and checking to see if it exists might help my case? Don't know, just providing as much detail as I can.

Comment: I just asked a similar question on superuser.  The answer might be helpful http://superuser.com/questions/348359/how-do-i-create-a-shortcut-for-a-find-and-replace-command-in-vim

Comment: I can see that helping a little but the main problem I'm having, is figuring out how to detect whether I'm in an unsaved buffer or a once saved file and then using that inside the command (or user command).

Comment: You must be careful using command-line abbreviations. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513380/vim-change-x-function-to-delete-buffer-instead-of-save-quit/7515418#7515418 for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Define a function like this:

```
function! CommandAbbrForEdit()
    if &modified
        return 'bd! | Edit'
    endif
    return 'e! | Edit'
endfunction
```

Then define your abbreviation like this:

```
cabbrev <expr> Edit! CommandAbbrForEdit()
```