# cmap :q to :bwipeout for VCSBlame/VCSAnnotate buffers (and other VCSCommand buffers)

Tags: svn, vim, vcscommand

I'm looking for a method to map `:q` to `:bwipeout` only for SVN blame buffers, as generated by `vcscommand.vim` and `:VCSBlame` so that my motor memory of `:q` takes hold when I want to eliminate those short-lived read-only buffers.

The buffer names begin with `SVN\ annotate <filename>`, and so I hoped this would match:

```
autocmd BufNew SVN\ annotate* cmap q bwipeout
```

However, the buffer name doesn't match this pattern.  How can I make this mapping happen locally for buffers like `SVN\ annotate*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VCSCommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90) (which I recommend) gives its buffers special filetypes. For `:VCSBlame` it's `svnannotate` if you use Subversion or `gitannotate` if you use Git.

From my limited trial, this line does exactly what you want:

```
autocmd FileType svnannotate cmap <buffer> q bwipeout
```

I've added `<buffer>` just in case but I think you can remove it safely.

Comment: @romani Yes, perfect. That's exactly what I wanted, also extensible, it appears, to `ft=svninfo` Thanks.

Comment: Be very careful with `cmap`. It can fire on any command line type actions. e.g. `/quick`, `?quick`, and middle of a command like `w ~/quick.txt`. see the following for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513380/vim-change-x-function-to-delete-buffer-instead-of-save-quit/7515418#7515418

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the VCSCommand plugin has a setting called `VCSCommandDeleteOnHide` which when set to non zero will `:bdelete` the buffer on a hide which this includes `:q`. Note: this will apply to all VCSCommand buffers.

```
let g:VCSCommandDeleteOnHide = 1
```

If you really want to wipe just the annotate the buffer you can do the following instead.

```
autocmd FileType svnannotate set bufhidden=wipe
```

See

```
:h VCSCommandDeleteOnHide
:h 'bufhidden'
```