# adding "cmap E e" in vimrc breaks plugins

Tags: vim, mapping, command, remap

I'm using lots of vim plugins like nerdtree, fugitive etc.

recently I was adding some new mappings and some of the plugins broke

I traced it down to the following line

```
cmap E e
```

WTF? :) why would it break NerdTree?

UPDATE: forgot to mantion how it breaks ;). I get the following error:

```
E492: Not an editor command: :NeRDTreeToggle
```

UPDATE2: Duh! I now know what happens. mapping E to e turns NERDTreeToggle into NeRDTreeToggle
so the new question is how to map E to e *properly*? i.e. so that ":E foo.txt" will do the same as ":e foo.txt"

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513380/vim-change-x-function-to-delete-buffer-instead-of-save-quit/7515418#7515418) will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

```
command -nargs=* -complete=file E e <args>
```

Comment: Ah, I was aiming for something else completely. Anyhow, ... glad you solved it! :) +1

Answer (score 1):

For I added below:

```
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()
filetype plugin indent on·
syntax on
```

in .vimrc file