# How to Eatchar in a multi-line Vim abbreviation

Tags: vim

I would like to trigger a multi line abbreviation in Vim, without entering the 'trigger' character, and with the cursor ending in insert mode at a particular location.

I am nearly there, but just failing to make it.

Thus far, i have added the following to my _vimrc:

```
" eat characters after abbreviation
function! Eatchar(pat)
    let c = nr2char(getchar(0))
    return (c =~ a:pat) ? '' : c
endfunction
iabbr <silent> if if ()<left><C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<CR>

:iabbr <silent> rfF <- function( )<CR>{<CR>  <CR>}<Esc>3k$h<Insert><c-r>=Eatchar('\m\s<bar>/')<cr>
```

Which is mostly successful, in that it yields the following when i type `rfF Ctr-]` to trigger the abbreviation's expansion:

```
<- function(  )
{

}
```

However, the outcome varies depending on how i trigger the abbreviation.

If i trigger with a `<space>` the space between the brackets expands:

```
<- function(  )
{

}
```

... and if i `<CR>`:

```
<- function( 
 )
{

}
```

I recently asked, and had [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858927/preventing-trailing-whitespace-when-using-vim-abbreviations), a question about preventing the characters that trigger an abbreviation from being added in the single line case.

Is this possible with multi-line abbreviations?

Comment: I really think something like [snipMate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim) is a better way to do this.

Comment: I am I right in assuming the cursor should appear in the function argument list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with.

```
" eat characters after abbreviation
function! Eatchar(pat)
    let c = nr2char(getchar(0))
    return (c =~ a:pat) ? '' : c
endfunction

inoreabbr <silent> rfF <- function()<cr>{<cr>}<esc>2k$i<c-r>=Eatchar('\m\s\<bar>\r')<cr>
```

The regex in this command `m\s\<bar>\r` will eat any white space or return character. I have also removed the extra space between the `{` and `}` because I imagine after you update the function parameter list you will exit back to normal mode then jump down a line with `j` then execute `o` to open a new line inside the function block.

Comment: +1. perfect. thanks v much. that's exactly what i wanted. I ended up going with `inoreabbr <silent> rfF <- function()<cr>{<cr><space><space><cr>}<esc>3k$i<c-r>=Eatchar('\m\s\<bar>\r')<cr`, but that's just personalising the detail.