# Vim abbreviations - end in insert mode

Tags: vim, abbreviation

Been through several guides to set up some simple Vim abbreviations.  I'm almost there, I just can't seem to find how to end IN insert mode.

What I have:

```
iab cl console.log()<Esc>F%s<c-o>:call getchar()<CR><Left><Left>
```

What happens:

```
cl expands to console.log() and the cursor is placed over )
```

What I want to happen:

```
Same thing except I want to enter insert mode.
```

What I've tried:

```
After <Left> I've tried:  <Insert>, i, and <Ins> with no luck.
```

Comment: I am confused about the `<Esc>F%s<c-o>:call getchar()<CR>` part. What is this supposed to be doing?

Comment: For removing trailing space, got it from: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_abbreviations_for_frequently-used_words

Comment: You should use a snippet plugin like snipmate or ultisnips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the abbreviation is encountering an error and stops executing.

This part `<Esc>F%s<c-o>:call getchar()<CR>` doesn't make sense to me and looks like it would be causing the error. Multiple parts of it could be the problem. But most likely the `F%` because it can't find a percent sign going backwards.

I think the fixed mapping should be something along the lines of this (however I don't think this does what you want) It does end in insert mode since the abbreviation completed successfully and the abbreviation doesn't do anything to exit insert mode.

```
iab cl console.log()<Left>
```

Take a look at this to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11865489/1890567 remove the trailing whitespace. from the abbreviation.

Comment: `<Esc>F%s<c-o>:call getchar()<CR>` removes the previous space and is taken from: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_abbreviations_for_frequently-used_words.  As for what you posted, while it does end in insert mode it puts a space before the cursor.

Comment: Your link provided the answer to the problem, thank you!

Comment: @diplosaurus yeah that part was taken out of context. It doesn't work unless you put a `%` in the abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution (using info from the thread FDinoff provided) was:

```
func Eatchar(pat)
  let c = nr2char(getchar(0))
  return (c =~ a:pat) ? '' : c
endfunc

iabbr cl console.log();<Left><Left><C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<CR>
```