# Vim: excute two commands with cabbrev

Tags: vim

I was wondering if it is possible to execute two commands with one cabbrev. I want to execute:

```
:set columns=170
:wincmd =
```

I tried

```
cnoreabbrev c2 :set columns=170 | :wincmd =
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cnoreabbrev c2 :set columns=170 <BAR> :wincmd =
```

Comment: You need to be careful with `cnoreabbrev` as they will expand in other command modes that do not make sense. e.g. `/c2` If this is the route you want to go I suggest you do something like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7515418/438329