# How to map (alias?) a command in vim

Tags: dictionary, vim

Lets say, hypothetically, that I always forget the command `:vsplit`, and always think it’s `:vdivide`.

Is there a way to map (I’m not sure if that’d be the right thing to call it, since it’s a command) one to the other?

Comment: something like "command Vdivide vsplit"?

Comment: Seems very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513380/vim-change-x-function-to-delete-buffer-instead-of-save-quit

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Like the poster there, I had no idea how to correctly define what I was trying to do, hence the difficulty searching for it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

User defined command can only start with an uppercase letter, so you can only add `:Vdivide` but not `:vdivide`.

Add in your `.vimrc`

```
 command Vdivide vsplit
```

Answer (score 8):

To get around the limitation that user-defined commands must start with an uppercase letter, I recommend the [cmdalias.vim - Create aliases for Vim commands](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=746) plugin. With it, you can do:

```
:Alias vdivide vsplit
```