# Is it possible to remap an Ex command in Vim (remap :Ack to :ack)?

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin

I use the Vim plugin [ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim), but I don't understand why the command is `:Ack` with a capital "A" (a little annoying to hold <kbd>shift</kbd>).

Is it possible to remap this to `:ack`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7513380/438329

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Built-in commands start with a lowercase character and custom commands start with an uppercase character. Those are the rules. Vim simply won't let you define a custom command starting with a lowercase.

If you don't like it, nothing prevents you from creating a normal mode mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>a :Ack<Space>
```

which is even faster than `:ack<Space>`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but It is not as simple as it sounds:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> ack getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdline() ==# 'ack' ? 'Ack' : 'ack'
```

Long story short vim does not provide a native way to create lowercase commands. Using mappings causes delays so abbreviations are preferred. The trick is to be careful when the abbreviation should expand as `cabbrev`'s expand at other times than just ex commands and in other places e.g. search. Here is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513380/vim-change-x-function-to-delete-buffer-instead-of-save-quit/7515418#7515418) talking about this point.

Hari Krishna Dara created a plugin: [cmdalias.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746). It uses a variation of the technique above