# How to map :Ag command to :ag

Tags: vim

I am using the plugin [ag.vim](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim) in Vim, and I want to do a simple re-mapping.

When I run **ag** with `:Ag` I want remap it to `:ag` so I don't have to use shift.
example: `:ag string_to_find` instead of `:Ag string_to_find`

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vim change :x function to delete buffer instead of save & quit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513380/vim-change-x-function-to-delete-buffer-instead-of-save-quit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't. Lowercase commands are reserved for built-in commands, and the norm/rules are to start custom commands with an uppercase character (just like with functions).

See [Is it possible to remap an Ex command in Vim (remap :Ack to :ack)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16821907/1076493)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but dding the following will allow you to just type 'ag' to search:

```
map ag :Ag
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If this is not what the OP asked for, and the post is 2 years old, I wonder why this would be posted as an answer? See the [how to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help understanding what an answer is.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: The downvoters are right and this is a bad answer. I'll leave it here so future searchers know it's wrong.

Try:

```
command: Ag ag
```

See :help command for more.

Comment: I have to put this to `.vimrc`?

Comment: No, don't remap custom commands to lowercase. If anything use a combination of leader.