# Why isn't this Vim mapping working?

Tags: vim

```
noremap :hsp :botright new
noremap :vsp :botright vnew
```

"Not an editor command: hsp"

I'm probably googling the wrong thing, but I can't find many results on aliasing vim commands. I can find tons of info about mapping keys to commands like my one for tabs:

```
noremap <C-t> :tabnew<CR>
```

But can't find commands mapped to other commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try command abbreviation?

```
ca hsp botright new
ca vsp botright vnew
```

You will have to initialize the expansion of the abbreviation by hitting the space key afterwards. Depending on the global vim configuration, expansion also happens automatically just when enter is pressed.

Comment: That did it thanks! My google-fu must just suck :( I kept getting things about shortcuts.

Comment: P.S. you answered in <10 minutes so I have to wait 10 minutes before marking yours correct.

Comment: this is not `alias`, it is abbreviation. you need a key (e.g. space) after the `hsp` to trigger the ab. I suggest command mapping.

Comment: Kent is right. Command abbreviations are dangerous! These abbreviations will expand in the middle of a command, in search, etc. May want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513380/vim-change-x-function-to-delete-buffer-instead-of-save-quit/7515418

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is simulating a command with a mapping. You're saying that when you press the 4 keys `:hsv` in normal mode, it should type out the keys `:botright new` (which would need a `<CR>` to run, as others have said), but it's not actually making the command `hsv`. You could make an actual command with a user command (`:h user-commands`). These must start with a capital letter, though.

```
:command Hsp botright new
:command Vsp botright vnew
```

Now you can type `:Hsp` and hit enter to run the command `botright new`.

Answer (score 0):

with your same mapping, I cannot get the `Not an editor command: hsp` error message with my vim (v7.4).

Your mapping works fine, but you don't have `<cr>` at the end, so when you press `:hsp` in normal mode, your mapping will switch to commandline mode, and put the mapped command there, without executing it. You have to manually press `Enter`.

@XZS's answer works, but keep in mind that it is an abbreviation(ab), not a mapping.  ab is not command aliases, it is not exactly same as mapping. For example, you have to press another key (like space) after `hsp` to trigger the ab. also, you cannot ab some special keys, this would be another limitation of ab.

There is `c(nore)map` for command mapping.

e.g. you could have:

```
cnoremap hsp botright new
```

with above line, as same as your original one, you have to manually press `Enter`, if you want it to be executed, you need add `<CR>` at the end of the line.

I think if I do this, I would create mapping.

Comment: This suffers the same problem as the `cnoreabbrev`. It will expand in unexpected places, e.g. searching. It would be better to create a command or use a special expression `cnoreabbrev`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513380/vim-change-x-function-to-delete-buffer-instead-of-save-quit/7515418

Comment: @PeterRincker thank you! you are right, the mapping will be triggered at `/ or ?` too...not nice. The `command` would be better. answer pending to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Creating command alias can be tricky:

- Using a simple `cabbrev` and/or `cmap` will cause expansions and mappings to fire in unexpected places like during searches with `/` and in the middle of filenames.
- `cmap`'s will have a visible delay in outputting to the screen which is why `cabbrev` is often used.

However there are a few ways to create a proper alias:

- Create a command via `:command`.

  - e.g. `command W w`
  - command's first letter must be a uppercase letter
  - must supply `-nargs`, `-bar`, `-complete`, and `-range` options according to the needs of your alias
- Expression `:cabbrev` to guard the abbreviation from expanding in in proper places.

  - expression mapping use the `<expr>` option
  - verify `getcmdtype()` is equal to `:`
  - verify the abbreviation is at the beginning of command line via `getcmdline()` or `getcmdpos()`
  - e.g. `cnoreabbrev <expr> W getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdline() ==# 'W' ? 'w' : 'W'`
- Use `:Alias` via the [cmdalias.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746) plugin by Hari Krishna Dara

  - e.g. `Alias W w`
  - uses an expression `cabbrev` under the covers similar to the technique above