# How to ignore case on vim commands?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to make vim ignore case on commands?

For example, I want vim to recognize `:vex` as `:Vex`.

Appreciate any pointers!

Comment: Related post: [vim change :x function to delete buffer instead of save & quit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7513380/438329)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple option, and a simplistic mapping (as in @romainl's answer, even when only applied to command-line mode) suffers from problems like noticeable delay or inadvertent application in other contexts.

I would recommend to use the [cmdalias.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746), which handles this quite well:

```
:Alias vex Vex
```

Comment: If you wish to do this w/o the plugin: `cnoreabbrev <expr> Vex getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'Vex' ? 'vex' : 'Vex'`

Answer (score 0):

You can find this simple solution out of the box:

```
nnoremap :vex :Vex
```

Comment: The issue there is scalability :(.