# I keep writing to `;` files by accident in Vim. Solution?

Tags: vim

I find my directories littered with files named `;` (semicolon) because I keep pressing `:w;` by accident. What's the easiest way to prevent this?

Comment: You can prevent this by paying attention to what you do.

Comment: @romainl : who never makes this kind of mistake, when often working on C-style files?

Comment: People who pay attention to what they do.

Comment: @romainl : It seems that vim's abbreviations were partly but explicitly created for people who do not always "pay attention" : please look at the example in `:h :abbreviate-verbose`

Comment: I do this *all the time*. Thank you for asking this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
:cabbr w; w
```

This will correct occurences of "w;" with "w" inside the command line.

See `:h abbreviations` for details.

Comment: Note: this will expand when searching as well. See [vim change :x function to delete buffer instead of save & quit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7513380/438329)